# Can I recognize if current iOS device is used for development?

Tags: iphone, ios, uidevice, rd

He All,
While I write my apps I thought maybe I could recognize if one of my future app users is a iOS developer.

For example check if the current device have any developer certificate installed?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you care?

Comment: what is the information that you can get on any particular iOS device in xcode in general? one of those may indicate what device you are using..

Comment: I just think about creating developers networks.. Using our apps as the network platform:for example, if I know that the current user is iOS developer, I can send him local notification to be my friend on linkedin...

Answer (score 0):

You could ask them within your app "are you a developer" and explain why you are asking, you don't have to try and do it covertly. Otherwise, no - you can't access that information.